# Where is the new System`ConvertersDump`$extensionMappings?

Tags: export, import, undocumented, compatibility, system-variables

I used to find the extensions mapping from `` System`ConvertersDump`$extensionMappings ``, which gives a mapping like "{"*.3ds" -> "3DS"...}". This seems in V13 it is removed, though some related contexts remain defined with no results:

```
Select[Names["System`*`*"], 
 StringMatchQ[#, "*extension*", IgnoreCase -> True] &]

(* {"System`Dump`ensureLibraryFileExtension", 
    "System`Dump`extension", 
    "System`ConvertersDump`extensions", 
    "System`ConvertersDump`extensions$", 
    "System`Dump`extension$", 
    "System`ConvertersDump`Utilities`Private`fileExtension", 
    "System`ConvertersDump`fileExtensions", 
    "System`FEDump`forceFileExtension", 
    "System`ConvertersDump`GetExtensionMappings", 
    "System`Dump`LibraryExtension"} *)
```

I checked all the above contexts, and none gives what I want.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found extension mappings in the `System` context, but here's a way to build mappings of file extentions and file formats that shouldn't be affected by version updates.

- Get file formats from [`$ImportFormats`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/$ImportFormats.html) and [`$ExportFormats`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/$ExportFormats.html).
- The function [`FileFormatProperties`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/FileFormatProperties.html) (introduced in v13) matches file formats to file extensions (`FileNamePatterns`). Some file formats have no matching `FileNamePatterns` so we remove them.

Make separate maps for Import Formats and Export Formats:

```
imMap = Cases[FileFormatProperties[#, "FileNamePatterns"] -> # &/@
  $ImportFormats, (e_ -> f_)/; Length[e] > 0];
(*{{*.3ds} -> 3DS, {*.7z} -> 7z, {*.aco} -> ACO, <<193>>,
   {*.xyz} -> XYZ, {*.zip, *.jar} -> ZIP, {*.zst} -> ZSTD}*)

exMap = Cases[FileFormatProperties[#, "FileNamePatterns"] -> # &/@
  $ExportFormats, (e_ -> f_)/; Length[e] > 0];
(*{{*.3ds} -> 3DS, {*.aco} -> ACO, {*.aif, *.aiff} -> AIFF, <<151>>,
   {*.zip, *.jar} -> ZIP, {*.zpr} -> ZPR, {*.zst} -> ZSTD}*)
```

The Import and Export maps could be combined, but test for conflicts.

Many file formats have multiple extensions, for example, `{*.zip, *.jar} -> ZIP`. Some extensions are used by multiple formats, one example: `*.json` is used by ExpressionJSON, GeoJSON, JSON, and RawJSON file formats.

Comment: The internal variables are internal for a reason and are not guaranteed to stay the same. FileFormatProperties is the correct and documented way to get extension mappings.

Answer (score 3):

By checking the output of

```
Export["a.txt", Export["a.txt",] // Trace] // SystemOpen
```

I find the variable

```
FileFormatDump`$INTERNALEXTENSIONMAPPINGS
```

has been used instead of

```
System`ConvertersDump`$extensionMappings
```

in `Export`/`Import` at least since *v13.3*. The variable `` FileFormatDump`$INTERNALEXTENSIONMAPPINGS `` outputs an `Association`(`<||>`) and has been a built-in variable at least since *v12.3*, BTW.

Comment: Those internal details are always subject to change. the correct way to do things is use FileFormatProperties.